# Blade laravel - yield and content

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

after some unuseful research I have to ask this.
I'm using laravel 5.6

I have my controller where I have

```
public function index()
{
    return view('layout.app');
}
```

where app.blade.php looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
</head>
<body>
@section('sidebar')
    This is the master sidebar.
@show

<div class="container">
    @yield('content')
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and child.blade.php is:

```
@extends('app')

@section('title', 'Page Title')

@section('sidebar')
    @parent

    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```

This files looks like laravel tutorial and they are, I tried with my own files and still got the same error, so to simplify I'm using laravel's ones.

So the thing is I'm never seeing child.blade.php 
Is there any common error where am I stuck?

I did this before and it went really well, I built the app really quick but now I can't find a solution.

Comment: you need to use `return view('child');` instead of `return view('layout.app');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need on controller is calling the child view

```
public function index()
{
    return view('child');
}
```

So controller will call the child view, and the child view will call the app view because you extend app view at the begining of child view